# Graph of $x^4+y^4=x^2+y^2$

Tags: graphing-functions, curves

The graph of solutions to $x^4+y^4=x^2+y^2$ is as follows:

[image]

Clearly the origin is also part of the graph. Is there a name for these kinds of points?

Comment: $\color{white}{............}?$

Comment: This is a singular point of an algebraic variety. Not all singular points are isolated. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_an_algebraic_variety

Comment: Very nice observation. It seems like that in your case this point is a trivial solution of the equation. And the nice thing about the graphical solution is that you can see that non-trivial solutions are infinitely close to each other.

Answer (score 4):

Your point is an isolated point of the *real locus* of the quartic algebraic curve $X^4+Y^4-X^2-Y^2=0$. But when you’re doing algebraic geometry, it’s always valuable to have the complex reality in mind. If you make the simple coordinate transformation $x=X, y=iY$, then you get $x^4+y^4-x^2+y^2=0$, whose real locus is a familiar-looking butterfly curve. The origin is still singular, but not isolated. You expect that if the defining polynomial is irreducible, then the (complex) locus will be connected.